# Excel formula for repeated sites

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm looking for some help with a formula. I have a dataset with repeated sites but with different number of visits per year. I could just do a simple formula for each separate site however, I have a couple hundred different sites surveyed at varying number of visits (see my Excel table for an example). The current formula is simple. It's just an average calculation (`=C3/SUM($C$2:$C$11)`), but I would like to automate this so I can use the drag down but having the formula recognize when there has been a site name change and include the total in the formula for that specific site.

[image: Excel table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SUMIFS():

```
=C2/SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,A2)
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something simple but I was using the SUMIF instead of SUMIFS. Much appreciated.

Comment: @IanFife `SUMIF(A:A,A2,C:C)` would work also, I just personally like to use `SUMIFS()` exclusively.  Keeps from having to remember the different layout.

Comment: @IanFife also remember to mark as correct if this helped answer you question.  You do that by clicking the check mark beside the answer.